# Image attached to Account object to be used in email sent from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, account, images, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using the Marketing Cloud Connector and need to have Salesforce users attach an image to the Account object (logo). The URL from that image needs to be passed in the synchronized data extension and used in emails.

We used this article and are close https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000007604&language=en_US&type=1

The problem is the image is not viewable to unauthenticated people. So the image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The Image would have to be public for that to work, unfortunately the URL you retrieve is going to need authentication.

The file needs to be in the Marketing Cloud Portfolio to be included in the email. You can use the API to to transfer the Image file to the Portfolio, refer to the [Portfolio Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/portfolio.htm) and also [Check this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/copying_an_image_from_a_website_into_the_portfolio.htm) on uploading an Image to the Portfolio

I hope this helps.